# Is it possible to call the SiteEdit editable content script to output the content from TBB using RenderComponentPresentation method?

Tags: tridion, siteedit

Is it possible to call the SiteEdit editable content script to output the content from TBB using RenderComponentPresentation method?

Currently, I am getting a red border line wrapped that content. When I roll over the top right corner icon, it is saying removed. However, the component content is not removed, any changes of the component template or page all have been republished and component itself is also not dynamic component.

The SiteEdit is working if I am calling the editable script directly from TBB, but if I am using `RenderComponentPresentation` method to call another Component Template to output that script. I only get the red border line and saying it has been removed.

**Editable script: (working directly from TBB)**

```
<!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="Content != ''" -->
<tcdl:ComponentField name="Content">${Content}</tcdl:ComponentField>
<!-- TemplateEndIf -->
```

Within TBB calling below method and always getting a red border    `RenderComponentPresentation(ComponentID, ComponentTemplateID)`

**Environment**: Tridion 2011, SiteEdit 2009 SP3, Windows Server 2008

Comment: Can you specify what you are doing in a Page Template, and what is in the Component Template? This is not clear in your question. Also, please consider committing to the Area 51 proposal for SDL Tridion at http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38335/tridion?referrer=eo63snjNlUWNn9xqeeO2NA2 using your stack overflow user account.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is not feasible with `RenderComponentPresentation` since what you're trying to do is nested component presentations. However you can get this by adding the siteedit markup tags directly with `IsQueryBased` to `true`

Please check the link for additional info (bottom of the section):  http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SiteEdit_2009_SP3/concept_0D0C929C17D74A6292B2AFE0C29F4DCD

Alternative approach is to add the below markup before your nested component presentation (IsQueryBased should be true):

```
<!-- Start SiteEdit Component Presentation: {
  "ID" : "MyCP23", "ComponentID" : "tcm:54-7894",
  "ComponentTemplateID" : "tcm:54-3201-32",
  "ComponentVersion" : 2,
  "IsQueryBased" : true,
  "SwapLabel" : "Left"
} -->
```

Comment: Thanks Ram. Only have chance to feedback on this. That's exactly what I have came across. It resolved the nested component presentation issues.

Answer (score 1):

If you are rendering a Component which is not on the current Page, then it is to be expected that SiteEdit considers it removed.

You will need to mark the Component Presentation as "query based" so SiteEdit knows not to expect it on the Page. This will disable the functionality which doesn't make sense (such as drag-and-drop to move the CP around on the Page) but will otherwise work the same.

To mark it as query-based, you will need to manually output the markup (see [Start SiteEdit Component Presentation command](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SiteEdit_2009_SP3/reference_StartSECP87A3F893FDAA4AD2956378B73245BC92)) or use some other tool to do it for you, like the functions [created by Frank van Puffelen](https://code.google.com/p/tridion-practice/wiki/TridionUI2012FunctionsForUseInHtmlTemplates) (**note:** I believe these only work for the 2011 version). Make sure the `IsQueryBased` parameter is set to `true`.